# Directory Table Base divided 4k, but my windows DTB / 4k = x ... 2

Tags: windows, x86-64, windbg

I did some experiments about memory analysis.
I have some problems..

almost Directory Table Base can divide 4k(4096) i know.
But my process in windows 10 (1909) have 0x14695e002 DTB.
So that can't divide 4k. 2 ramians.

Why my windows have that value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirBase / Directory Table base is the value of the CR3 register for the current process. As you may know the CR3 is the base register which (indirectly) points to the base of the PML4 (or PDPT) table and is used when switching between process, which basically switches their entire physical memory.

## Base CR3

As you may have seen in the Intel manual the 4 lower bits of the CR3 should be ignored by the CPU (Format of the CR3 register with 4-Level Paging):

[image: CR3 register]

## 4-level paging

Now if you look closely at the at the Intel Manual (`Chapter 4.5; 4-level Paging`).

> A logical processor uses 4-level paging if CR0.PG = 1, CR4.PAE = 1, and IA32_EFER.LME = 1

Respectively: Paging; Physical Address Extension; Long Mode Enable.

> Use of CR3 with 4-level paging depends on whether process context identifiers (PCIDs) have been enabled by setting CR4.PCIDE.

## CR4.PCIDE

CR4.PCIDE is documented in the Intel Manual (`Chapter 2.5 Control Registers`):

> CR4.PCIDE
> PCID-Enable Bit (bit 17 of CR4) — Enables process-context identifiers (PCIDs) when set. See Section 4.10.1, “Process-Context Identifiers (PCIDs)”. Can be set only in IA-32e mode (if IA32_EFER.LMA = 1).

[image]

So when CR4.PCIDE is set, the 12 (0:11) lower bits of CR3 are used as PCID, that is, a "Process-Context Identifier" (bits 12 to M-1, where M is usually 48, are used for the physical address for the base of the PML4 table).

## PCIDs

PCIDs are documented in the Intel Manuel (`Chapter 4.10.1; Process-Context Identifiers (PCIDs)`):

> Process-context identifiers (PCIDs) are a facility by which a logical processor may cache information for multiple linear-address spaces. The processor may retain cached information when software switches to a different linear address space with a different PCID.

And a little bit further in the same chapter:

> When a logical processor creates entries in the TLBs [...] and paging-structure caches [...], it associates those entries with the current PCID.

So basically PCIDs (as far as I understand them) are a way to selectively control how the TLB and paging structure caches are preserved or flushed when a context switch happens.

**Some** of the instruction that operate on cacheability control (such as CLFLUSH, CLFLUSHOPT, CLWB, INVD, WBINVD, INVLPG, INVPCID, and memory instructions with a non-temporal hint) will check the PCID to either flush everything that concerns a precise PCID or flush only a part of the cache (such as the TLB) and keep everything in relation to a given PCID.

For example the [`INVPLG`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/invlpg) instruction:

> The INVLPG instruction normally flushes TLB entries only for the specified page; however, in some cases, it may flush more entries, even the entire TLB. The instruction invalidates TLB entries associated with the current PCID and may or may not do so for TLB entries associated with other PCIDs.

The [`INVPCID`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/invpcid) specifically uses the PCIDs:

> Invalidates mappings in the translation lookaside buffers (TLBs) and paging-structure caches based on process-context identifier (PCID)

Why it is always 2 (as far as I can see, it's always 2 for every processes in the system) on Windows, I don't know.